# OperationalErrors - no such column django - ForeignKey

Tags: django, model, django-migrations

I have this field in my model:

```
customer = models.ManyToManyField(Customer)
```

Due to some changes, I realized that I have to change the relationship to this:

```
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

I have tried to do the  `makemigrations app_name`  and  `migrate`  again and again but it still produces the error. I also have tried deleting the existing data of the model in the admin site.

Answer (score 1):

A simple change from ManyToManyField to ForeignKey is not possible without data loss. Problems with migrations **can be solved by splitting** an impossible migration **to smaller migrations**. e.g. if data are important

A) with data loss:

- delete ManyToManyField
- makemigrations
- add ForeignKey
- makemigrations

B) with partial data loss, that only first element of ManyToManyField will be converted for every object to ForeignKey:
Add ForeignKey with other name, `makemigrations`, `makemigrations --empty`, edit it to [Data Migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to copy the column data, remove ManyToManyField; `makemigrations`, `makemigrations --empty`,
 [edit it to rename the field](https://gist.github.com/dhbradshaw/e2bdeb502b0d0d2acced).